# d3: css rule doesn't apply to svg element

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to add a legend with a background-color in d3. The legend shows up fine, but the background color doesn't show.

I am wondering why that is the case. Is that because I can't apply css rule to svg element?

My css code:

```
svg .legend {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888;
}
```

Part of my d3 code that adds the legend:

```
var legend = vis.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("x", WIDTH - 65)
    .attr("y", 35)
    .attr("height", 150)
    .attr("width", 150);

     legend.append("rect")
         .attr("x", WIDTH - 95)
         .attr("y", 45)
         .attr("width", 10)
         .attr("height", 10)
         .style("fill", "orange");

     legend.append("text")
         .attr("x", WIDTH - 75)
         .attr("y", 55)
         .text("Average Price");
```

Comment: Legend is a `g` element, which is simply a *group* of elements, but has no physical representation itself. Hence it does not display your background, because there is nothing to give a background to. Your easiest option would be to draw a background rectangle with a class and apply styling to that.

Comment: The background-color CSS property does not apply to SVG elements (except for the root `<svg>` element). Supported properties are listed here: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html

Comment: @JSBob could you get around that by specifying a sub element? e.g. in this case .legend rect {css}?